# Why am I able to update HttpOnly cookie?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, httponly, cookie-httponly

I'm setting a cookie to HttpOnly in the Node layer of an Express + VueJS application before the response from the user login endpoint is dispatched as follows:

```
res.cookie('ms-sso', response.session.token, { httpOnly: true })
```

Based on going to Chrome > Application > Cookies, it appears that setting the cookie to HttpOnly in this fashion works:

[image]

However, it was my understanding that these cookies cannot be updated and/or accessed from the client-side, only the server-side. Yet from within the client-side code, I'm able to do something like this:

```
document.cookie = `ms-sso=banana`
console.log(document.cookie) // shows `ms-sso=banana` in the console
```

Nevertheless, when I type in and enter document.cookie in the console, it shows "" as expected. Am I misunderstanding the definition of being editable with HttpOnly turned on and all of these observations are expected behavior?

Comment: The client side `document.cookie = 'ms-sso=banana'` overwrite the one set using Node.

Comment: @LGSon are you saying that the new cookie is not HttpOnly?

Comment: Yes and no ... check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52646845/overwriting-httponly-cookie-by-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1